# SQL aggregation query for SUM, but only allow positive sums (otherwise 0)

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I want to query an orders table and show the customer id and the total of all his orders, however the orders can have positive or negative totals.

```
select customer_id, SUM(order_total) from orders group by customer_id;
```

Now my question - how can I achieve the following in one sql query:

**If the total sum is positive, I want to display it as is; if the total sum is negative, I just want to display 0 instead the actual amount.**

What I am looking for is a function that can handle this, similar to the `IFNULL` function (`IFNULL(SUM(order_total),0)`), but instead of checking for null, it should check for a negative result.

Pseudo code:

```
IFNEGATIVE(SUM(order_total),0)
```

Is there a simple way in standard sql (or specifically in Mysql 5.5, would also be ok).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_id,
  CASE 
    WHEN SUM(order_total) < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE SUM(order_total)
  END
  FROM orders 
  GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Check your execution plan, but the 2 `SUM`s will probably be optimized to a single `SUM` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't used cases in sql often, good to know :) I think some of the other answers provided (i.e. IF also work), however, let me accept this vote here, I upvote the other ones as well.

Answer (score 8):

Try with:

```
select customer_id, GREATEST( SUM(order_total),0) from orders group by customer_id;
```

Comment: I like this better as well for readability/maintainability, but it a quick check on my end for a similar scenario shows the same execution plan in SQL 2012 - SQL server can figure out that you really only need it once.

Comment: And I realize this is an old question and just saw that it's actually for MySQL, but this seems like a pretty low hanging optimization - I'd bet MySQL could do it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested, but something like this should do it:

```
SELECT customer_id , IF( SUM(order_total) > 0, SUM(order_total), 0) AS sum FROM orders GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand its only wrap it with ***GREATEST***

```
SELECT customer_id, GREATEST(0,SUM(order_total)) 
FROM orders GROUP BY customer_id;
```

look on the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

Comment: This will sum only possitive orders. The OP asks for the sum of all the orders.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use a CASE statement?

Something like:

```
CASE WHEN [Field] < 0 THEN 0
```

Or did I miss something?

Comment: you missed something. it's the *sum* that shouldn't be negative - individual rows can be mixed +ve and -ve as long as the sum is not negative

Comment: it almost felt too simple!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id,case when (sum(amount)<0) then 0 else sum(amount) end  from tblsum group by Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try;

```
select 
  (sum(fld) + abs(sum(fld))) / 2
from tbl
```

Comment: shouldn't it be (sum(fld) + sum(abs((fld))) / 2

Answer (score -2):

To only display positive Use HAVING thus:

```
select customer_id, SUM(order_total) from orders group by customer_id HAVING SUM(order_total) > 0;
```

Otherwise use case as listed elsewhere here

Comment: That will limit his search, but it won't display 0 when the sum is negative.

Comment: Realised mis-understood the 'display zero' but left answer here for other cases...